# Websites that offer book/movie/story analyses useful for writers?

Tags: planning, websites, text-analysis

I was wondering if there are any websites that offer analyses of stories, written or otherwise, with the intention to teach people something about writing and storytelling?

I realize I can just google for analyses on specific works of litterature, but I thought maybe someone had made a more collected effort. Pehaps even divided into different aspects of writing/storytelling, such as prose, characters or story structure.

Might be tempting for lazy kids who don't want to do their homework, though...

Comment: Yeah, I thought of SparkNotes for specific literature. It's not really intended to teach people to write by example, but rather illuminate literary techniques used in specific lines/passages for the purpose of allowing a student to write an essay on those devices. My English class currently uses _The Bedford Reader_, (not a huge fan) which has essays by authors on how to write/storytell. I also know that's not a website which is why this isn't an answer.

Comment: Something like SparkNotes was exactly what I was after! Preferably with more books, though.

Answer (score 3):

Try http://tvtropes.org. It's an exhaustive list of tropes and idioms and written in kind of a smart-alecky tone, but among the snark there's genuinely useful analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link for movies. John Truby's analysis of many Hollywood movies. 
http://www.truby.com/reviewarc.html